# Phone is locked with an impossible to enter password

Tags: lock-screens, keyboard, password

As it appeared, the on-screen keyboard for entering the unlock password is missing English layout, although it for sure was present when the password has been created.
Now the situation appears really bad:

- the phone (TP-LINK Neffos C9A, Android 8.1 NFUI 8.0) is locked,
- the password is not possible to enter because of missing keyboard layout,
- option for adding keyboard languages is not available,
- there is no option "Forgotten password" and
- Android Device Manager responds "Can't reach device" with either WiFi or 3G connection.

How to unlock the phone in such situation?

Comment: Have you tried to connect an USB keyboard via USB OTG?

Comment: @Robert - thank you for the hint - I've tried a USB keyboard and was able to enter English letters, but neither Shift no Caps Lock were giving capital letters. Same happened with another USB keyboard

Comment: @Robert, thank you again - I've managed to enter caps with holding both Shift and a key. You saved me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case there is a problem with the on-screen keyboard most devices support to use an USB keyboard connected via USB On-The-Go (OTG) adapter to the phone - if the phone supports USB OTG at all.

The simpler an USB keyboard is the more likely it will work - keyboards with integrated USB hub and/or readers for smartcard or sd-card often cause problems and may not work.

Note that the USB keyboard works like a regular keyboard (not like the on-screen keyboard): key combinations like have be pressed at the same time, not one after another.

Answer (score 0):

For people seeking for other answers, there is a flashable Zip file which deletes any lock screens. However you'd need a device with a custom recovery such as TWRP.
Just flash [the Zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2780696) and your lock screen will be gone on next restart.